# Logical operators in JavaScript — how do you use them?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I don't understand how `&&`, `||`, and `!` work... both with bools and other data types. How do you use them?

Comment: Closely related: [Does JavaScript have "Short-circuit" evaluation?](/q/12554578/4642212).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All values in JavaScript are either “truthy” or “falsy”.

- `a && b` evaluates to the first falsy operand,
- `a || b` evaluates to the first truthy operand.

Both operators will not evaluate any operands after the one the return.
If all operands don’t match, they will evaluate to the last one.

- `!a` evaluates to `true` if `a` is falsy and `false` if `a` is truthy.

---

All values are truthy except the following, which are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy):

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `false`
- `+0`
- `-0`
- `NaN`
- `0n`
- `""`
- `document.all`

Comment: It should state "All *values* are truthful...", since i.e. `undefined` is a value, but there's also the variable `undefined` which holds this value, by default. Also `NaN` is not equal to anything, not even to itself.

Comment: @Ivo: 1: Fixed. 2: That's irrelevant; `!NaN` is `true`, so `NaN` is falsy.

Comment: Still NaN == NaN is false. So it's still a special case from the above list one might think that NaN works like every other falsy value.

Comment: @Ivo: SLaks is only listing JavaScript's falsy values. He isn't claiming anything else about `NaN` or any of the other values.

Comment: I know this is ancient history but `document.all`?

Comment: @Pointy - It's a quirk of web history. :-) Early on, `document.all` was a Microsoft-ism and IE didn't support the fledgling DOM standard, so code would do `if (document.all) { /* MS-specific code */ } else { /* DOM standard code */ }`. Time moved on and A) MS implemented DOM standards, and B) Other browsers added `document.all` to support code that relied on it unconditionally. But the code in those pages didn't move on. To avoid having code written like that taking the Microsoft-only branch, Chrome and Firefox made `document.all` *falsy*. Eventually so did IE. It's been standardized now. :-D

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test that *both* of two conditions are truthy then use &&:

```
if (isX && isY)
{
     // Do something.
}
```

If you want to test that *one or both* of two conditions are truthy then use ||:

```
if (isX || isY)
{
     // Do something.
}
```

The `!` inverts a boolean (a truthy value becomes false and vice versa).

Comment: What about `document.write("Cat"||"Dog")`?

Comment: @DarkLightA: I'd suggest that you don't write code like that! It causes implicit conversions and it will confuse everyone.

Comment: It shouldn't confuse anyone. Short-circuiting has been a common idiom in javascript since around 5 years ago. Crockford calls `||` the default operator so `"Cat" || "Dog"` should read `cat, defaults to dog`. Personally I read it as `cat, otherwise dog`.