# JavaScript combining && statements in a variable to be true or false

Tags: javascript, variables

just a quick question. I cannot find anything relating to this since I don't really see how to explain it... but, if I combine two bool values using an && to make another variable, what will happen?

```
var is_enabled = isEnabled() && isSupported();
```

If isEnabled() is false and isSupported() is true, will it equal false?

Comment: Did you try it?  What did it output?

Comment: If your functions are really returning the boolean constants `true` or `false`, then yes.

Comment: Q: If isEnabled() is false and isSupported() is true, will it equal false?  A: You're kidding, right?  Q: Did you *try* it?  Q: Can you think of any possible reason it *wouldn't* be false???

Comment: I cannot try it as I am on mobile atm but this question came to mind. Basically my question was asking if I could combine the two functions with an && without error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Logical operators in JavaScript — how do you use them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535647/logical-operators-in-javascript-how-do-you-use-them)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Javascript the `&&` and `||` operators are slightly strange. It depends on if the value is "falsy" (zero, `undefined`, `null`, empty string, `NaN`) or truthy (anything else, including empty arrays).

With `&&` if the first value is "falsy", then the result of the operation will be the first value, otherwise it will be the second value. With `||` if the first value is "falsy" then the result of the operation will be the second value, otherwise it will be the first value.

Example:

```
var a = 5 && 3; // a will be 3
var a = 0 && 7; // a will be 0

var a = 1 || 2; // a will be 1
var a = 0 || 2; // a will be 2
```

This is very useful if you want to replace this:

```
if (x == null){
  x = 5;
}
```

With:

```
x = x || 5;
```

So in short, if `isEnabled()` is truthy then `is_enabled` will be set to whatever `isSupported()` returns. If `isEnabled()` is falsy, then `is_enabled` will be set to whatever that falsy value is.

Also as Robert pointed out, there is short-circuiting:

```
var x = 5 || infinite_loop();
var x = false && infinite_loop();
```

In both cases, the `infinite_loop()` call doesn't happen, since the two operations are short-circuited - `||` doesn't evaluate the second value when the first value is truthy, and `&&` doesn't evaluate the second value when the first value is falsy.

Comment: But in all cases this kind of syntax is a bad practice correct ? because of code readability

Comment: I've never heard of it being called bad practice, and IMO it reads just fine. But then again I'm used to seeing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

The result of `false && true` is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If isEnabled() is false and you use && then isSupported() will never be called because the evaulation will short circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If any operand of `&&` operator is *falsy* (`false`, 0, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `""`) then `is_enabled` will be assigned the first falsy value.

If all operands of `&&` operator is not *falsy*, then the last operand will be assigned to `is_enabled`.

Answer (score 1):

is_enabled would only be set to true if isEnabled and isSupported are both true. So if isEnabled is false, and isSupported is true, is_enabled would be false.

Answer (score 1):

yes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isEnabled() {
    return false;
}

function isSupported() {
    return true;
}

var is_enabled = isEnabled() && isSupported();

alert(is_enabled);  // = 'false'
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

if both functions return only true or false, then it just works as a normal && with booleans.

```
1 && 1 = 1
1 && 0 = 0
0 && 1 = 0
0 && 0 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, && is only true if and only if both expressions are true.

So back to your question, true && false will equal to false, so yes.

You can also try to test these expressions yourself using the console function on firebug or chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it's to just add a single `&` and apply an `AND` operation to those booleans, making it that if both of them are true, then `is_enabled` will be true.

```
var is_enabled = isEnabled() & isSupported();
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to Pointy to pointing out that my syntax is incorrect, this should apply to C language, guess i just got confused

Comment: `&&` is also an `AND` operation.  `&` is a bitwise `AND`.

Comment: It should be noted that the semantics of `&` are significantly different from `&&`, particularly in that `&` always evaluates both expressions while `&&` only evaluates the right-hand side when the left-hand side is `true`.

Comment: Also (had to check the spec to make sure :-)  the bitwise-logical operators always return an integer value, not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see what are the possible cases of tests:

```
var str='My dummy string';
var str2='My other dummy string';
var falsy1= 1==2;
var truthy1= true;
var truthy2= true;
var falsy2= false;
```

then:

```
console.log('Both bool true:', truthy1 && truthy2); // <== Both bool true: true
console.log('Bool true and string:', truthy1 && str); // <== Bool true and string: My dummy string
console.log('String and bool true:', str && truthy1); // <== String and bool true: true
console.log('Falsy operation and string:', falsy1 && str); // <== Falsy operation and string: false
console.log('Bool false and string:', falsy2 && str); // <== Bool false and string: false
console.log('Both bool false and true:', falsy1 && truthy1); // <== Both bool false and true: false
console.log('Both bool true and false:', truthy1 && falsy1); // <== Both bool true and false: false
console.log('Operation false and bool true:', falsy2 && truthy1); // <== Operation false and bool true: false
console.log('Operation false and bool false:', falsy2 && falsy1); // <== Operation false and bool false: false
console.log('Both strings:', str2 && str); // <== Both strings: My dummy string
console.log('Both strings:', str && str2); // <== Both strings: My other dummy string   
console.log('String and bool false:',  str && falsy1); // <== String and bool false: false  
console.log('String and 2 bool false and true:',  str && falsy1  && truthy1); // <== String and 2 bool false and true: false
console.log('3 bool false and true and true:',  falsy1 && truthy1 && truthy2); // <== 3 bool false and true and true: false
console.log('3 bool false and false and true:',  falsy1 && falsy1 && truthy1); // <== 3 bool false and false and true: false
console.log('Bool false and operation false and bool true:',  falsy1 && falsy2 && truthy1); // <== Bool false and operation false and bool true: false
console.log('3 bool true and true and false:',  truthy2 && truthy1 && falsy1); // <== 3 bool true and true and false: false
console.log('String and 2 bool false and true:',  str && falsy1 && truthy1); // <== String and 2 bool false and true: false
console.log('String and 2 bool true and false:',  str && truthy1 && falsy1); // <== String and 2 bool true and false: false
console.log('2 bool false and true and string:',   falsy1 && truthy1 && str); // <== 2 bool false and true and string: false
console.log('2 bool true and false string:',  truthy1 && falsy1 && str); // <== 2 bool true and false string: false
console.log('Bool true and string and bool false:',  truthy1 && str && falsy1); // <== Bool true and string and bool false: false
console.log('Bool false and string and bool true:',  falsy1 && str && truthy1); // <== Bool false and string and bool true: false
```

And the bonus:

```
console.log('The existence of a string:',  !!str); // <== The existence of a string: true
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
If first is not falsy then second,
else  first.

**example :** if isEnabled() returns false, then `false` is the result.

otherwise If isEnabled() is true,
then **whatever isSupported() returns** is the result.

Now `false` and `true` were used to simplify the answer, false can be any **falsy** value.

> Examples of truthy and falsy values:
>
> var string = ""; // <-- falsy
>
> var filledString = "some string in here"; // <-- truthy
>
> var zero = 0; // <-- falsy
>
> var numberGreaterThanZero // <-- truthy
>
> var emptyArray = []; // <-- truthy, we'll explore more about this next
>
> var emptyObject = {}; // <-- truthy

Answer (score -3):

The result of a successful Boolean operation such as "&&" is a Boolean value.  As such, the result of `isEnabled() && isSupported()` will be a Boolean value which will then be assigned to is_enabled

Comment: That is not correct; in JavaScript, `&&` does not necessarily produce a boolean result.