# Understanding this custom hasPrototypeProperty function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How does this function determine if a property exists on the `prototype`?

```
function hasPrototypeProperty(object, name){
    return !object.hasOwnProperty(name) && (name in object);
}
```

I am confused by two things:

What is the `!` operator doing to the `hasOwnProperty` method?

And while `&&` seems to saying `(name in object)` has to be true as well, I am kind of not sure...

I know `hasOwnProperty` will only return `true` if the property exists on a instance, but I read it still checks the `prototype`, if so, what for? That seems like a strange thing to do if the instance is the only thing which matters?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the ! operator doing to the hasOwnProperty method?

It's the [boolean NOT operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4535647/1048572). It doesn't do anything to the method, but to the result of the call.

> And while && seems to saying (name in object) has to be true as well, I am kind of not sure...

Yes, that's what it does.

> I know hasOwnProperty will only return true if the property exists on a instance, but I read it still checks the prototype, if so, what for?

Not, it does not check the prototype. The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) does however.

So basically that `hasPrototypeProperty` function will return `true` iff the `object` has no own property with the given `name`, but there is a possible inherited property with that `name` on the `object`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's checking **exclusively** if an [enumerable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) is inherited.

To do this it checks the `hasOwnProperty()` method to see if the property in the object **doesn't** (! **not operator**)  directly belong to object:

> that are not set in hasOwnProperty `!object.hasOwnProperty(name)`.

---

And if the **[in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)** returns true it means it belongs to the object's prototype chain

> even if it's not a direct property it can be called on object since they belong to the inheritance

---

But remember `name in object` returns true only if the property is enumerable;
 for ex.: `toString()` won't ( because it's a nonenumerable property).