# Iterating through class names and hiding some in vanilla js

Tags: javascript

Stumped and I am sure there is an easy explanation to this.

So I want to iterate through all of the class names called 'images' and hide say the last 4:

```
images = document.getElementsByClassName("images");


for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  if(images[i] == images[5] || images[6] || images[7] || images[8]) {
    images[5].style.display = "none";
    images[6].style.display = "none";
    images[7].style.display = "none";
    images[8].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Is there anyway of making this code shorter? Seems a bit laborious if you were to have loads of images.

No frameworks on this please! Many thanks for your help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535647/logical-operators-in-javascript-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: Before thinking of *shorter* code, think of *correcting* your code. It does not do what you intended.

Comment: You could try something like `let lastFourImages = images.slice(-4)`, then do a  `switch` over those. But @trincot is pointing you to good sources.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for a shorter version?

```js
images = document.getElementsByClassName("images");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  if( i >= images.length-4 ) { // Last 4
    images[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
1<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><br/>
2<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><br/>
3<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><br/>
4<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><br/>
5<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
```

Or another Version mentioned by @Hector

```js
images = [...document.getElementsByClassName("images")].slice(-4); // last 4

for( let i in images ) {
  images[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
1<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><br/>
2<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><br/>
3<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><br/>
4<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50"><br/>
5<img class="images" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
```

Comment: My bad, meant to say loop, not switch.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. You can hide the last 4 by doing some simple math and then hiding by index.

```js
images = document.getElementsByClassName("images");

const numberToHide = 4;
const totalImages = images.length;
for (var i = 0; i < totalImages; i++) {
  const indexToHide = totalImages - numberToHide;
  if (i >= indexToHide) {
    images[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="images">1</div>
<div class="images">2</div>
<div class="images">3</div>
<div class="images">4</div>
<div class="images">5</div>
<div class="images">6</div>
<div class="images">7</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the number of elements subtracted by the value of i in the for loop is less than or equal to 4 to hide the last 4 elements.

```html
1<img class="image" src="somesource">
<br/>
2<img class="image" src="somesource">
<br/>
3<img class="image" src="somesource">
<br/>
4<img class="image" src="somesource">
<br/>
5<img class="image" src="somesource">
<br/>
6<img class="image" src="somesource">
<br/>
7<img class="image" src="somesource">
<br/>
8<img class="image" src="somesource">
<br/>
<script>
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("image");


for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  if(images.length - i <= 4){
   images[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `if(images[i] == images[5] || images[6] || images[7] || images[8])` is not how you compare a value with several others. The `||` operator is intended for boolean logic, so you would need to repeat the `==` comparison to make that correct (but not short). See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values).

The shortest, in combination with matching the DOM elements, is probably achieved with `Array.from`:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".images"),(img,i)=>img.style.display=i>4?"none":"");
```

```html
<div class="images">0</div>
<div class="images">1</div>
<div class="images">2</div>
<div class="images">3</div>
<div class="images">4</div>
<div class="images">5</div>
<div class="images">6</div>
<div class="images">7</div>
```