# Diffrence between if(a) & if(a!=null && a!=undefined)

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a lot of issues while populating data in the DOM, because of there are no values in the objects or arrays, which I want to use.

For example, I have an object:

```
var obj = {
  name: 'rajat',
  age: 20
}
```

and I am populating data on HTML Elements Dynamically, Like below:

```
<p id='paragraph'></p>  

var data = document.getElementById('paragraph');
data.innerHTML = obj.name;
```

Now, I just want to add condition before assigning value to HTML element, I am confused by `if(obj.a)` and `if(obj.a!=undefined && obj.a!=null)`.

Can anyone please explain the difference between the two?

Comment: See [Logical operators in JavaScript — how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535656/4642212).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (obj.a)
```

tests to see whether `obj.a` is not any of `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, `false`, or `""` (the empty string).

```
if (obj.a != undefined && obj.a != null)
```

just checks for `null` and `undefined`, and is exactly the same as

```
if (obj.a != null)
```

because that's how `!=` is defined. In fact this is one of the few cases where using `!=` is preferable to `!==`.

[edit] it's pointed out in a comment that because `-0` exists in JavaScript (as it does in all IEEE floating point systems), that's also "falsey".

Comment: This list is incomplete. The full list is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535656/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox ok you got me with `-0` but `document.all`? That can't possibly be in the language spec.

Comment: @Pointy MDN: *Provides access to all elements in the document. This is a legacy, non-standard property and should not be used.*

Comment: @Luca sure, and it'll be `null` or `undefined`, but the language spec does not know about or care about browser APIs.  In other words there's no difference as far as JavaScript is concerned between `document.all` and `document.zimbabwe`

Answer (score 5):

`if(obj.a)` will evaluate to `true`, if the value of `obj.a` is truthy, everything is truthy, but

- `false`
- `0`
- `+0` and `-0`
- `""`, `''` and ``` `` ``` - strings of length 0
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`

`if(obj.a!=undefined && obj.a!=null)` will evaluate to true even, if `obj.a` is

- `false`
- `0`
- `+0` and `-0`
- `""`, `''` and ``` `` ``` - strings of length 0
- `NaN`

So it's less exclusive, and `obj.a` can be more values without the `if` not being entered.

Comment: Is `false` not the same as `false`?

Comment: I think the false got doubled up by mistake, as a matter of fact it is fixed as I am typing

Comment: The answer to the second `if` is a little confusing. It will also evaluate to true if `obj.a` is "hello", 215, or just about anything else. It would probably be useful to know when it evaluates to false.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I thought the "**even**, if" covered that

Comment: This list is still incomplete. The full list is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535656/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox I omitted `document.all` since it has nothing to do with the question, and +/-0 will be added in an edit about now.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, `if` evaluates the "truthiness" of the condition.  The following values are "falsey":

- `false`
- `undefined`
- `null`
- ""
- +/-0
- NaN

Anything else is evaluated as `true`.  So in your case, `if(obj.a)` will evaluate false if `obj.a` is any of the above bulleted values.  However `if(obj.a != undefined && obj.a != null)` will only check for those two values (`undefined` and `null`) specifically, meaning that if the value is any of the other falsey items, it will still evaluate true.

This blog serves as a good resource for further explanation: https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Comment: Also `NaN` is "falsey".

Comment: This is still incomplete. The full list is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535656/4642212).

Comment: @Xufox While that list may be more explicit, I'd argue that `0` implies `+/-0`.  I recognize that they're different, but both are 0.  That said, I'll make that explicit in the post. The only other difference is `document.all`, which will actually evaluate `true` in old IE browsers (an unlikely scenario, but not impossible). I would consider it bad practice to assume `document.all` is falsey.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with JavaScript **type-coercion** which is a concept which determines how values are converted to different types. JavaScript is a loosely typed language (no strict types like int, string, ect.).

Therefore if the JS engine comes across an `if` statement and has convert the expression to a boolean.

For example:

```js
// Boolean converts the value to a boolean
// The following values are converted to false, the rest is converted to true

console.log(Boolean(0));  // false
console.log(Boolean(''));  // false
console.log(Boolean(null));  // false
console.log(Boolean(undefined));  // false
console.log(Boolean(NaN));  // false
console.log(Boolean(false));  // false

// Bonus you can also convert to boolean really concise with the double !! operator 
// For example:

console.log(!!5);  // true
console.log(!!'random');  // true
```

Therefore the code:

```
if(a!=null && a!=undefined){}
```

is not the same as

```
 if(a){}
```

Because you miss the other types which will be converted to false. For example:

```js
if(NaN){
  console.log('I wont log');
}
```