# I have returned two values but console displaying only one value.. what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, function

In the below function, I was expecting two values to be returned but I am getting only one value in the console.

```
var contacts =[
            {"firstname": "karthi","lastname": "kosuri","mobile": "9999666888889","likes":["pizza","icecream","curdrice"]},
            {"firstname": "sathvik","lastname": "kosuri","mobile": "9849488486","likes":["biryani","vada","idly"]},
            {"firstname": "neelu","lastname": "kosuri","mobile": "892736636","likes":["annam","pappu","charu"]},
            {"firstname": "kesav","lastname": "kosuri","mobile": "748484848484","likes":["kudithi","sambar","bokka"]}
        ];

    function contactlookup(name, prop){
        for( var i=0; i< contacts.length;i++){
            if(contacts[i].firstname=== name){
                return contacts[i][prop];
            }
        }
        return "no such name";
    }
    var data = contactlookup("karthi", "kosuri");
    console.log(data);
```

Comment: Do you mean you expected `return name && prop` to return both `name` *and* `prop`? That's **not** what that means; `x && y` is effectively `x ? y : x`, it will only resolve to *one* of those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use array find  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```js
var contacts = 
    [ { firstname: 'karthi'
      , lastname:  'kosuri'
      , mobile:    '9999666888889'
      , likes:     [ 'pizza', 'icecream', 'curdrice' ] 
      } 
    , { firstname: 'sathvik'
      , lastname:  'kosuri'
      , mobile:    '9849488486'
      , likes:     [ 'biryani', 'vada', 'idly' ] 
      } 
    , { firstname: 'neelu'
      , lastname:  'kosuri'
      , mobile:    '892736636'
      , likes:     [ 'annam', 'pappu', 'charu'] 
      } 
    , { firstname: 'kesav'
      , lastname:  'kosuri'
      , mobile:    '748484848484'
      , likes:     [ 'kudithi', 'sambar', 'bokka'] 
      } 
    ];

function contactlookup(name, prop)
{
  let lookup = contacts.find(elm=>elm.firstname===name && elm.lastname===prop )
  return (lookup)? lookup : 'no such name' 
}


var data = contactlookup('karthi', 'kosuri')

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only return **one** value.

> ```
> return name && prop;
> ```

This returns the result of evaluating `name && prop` (see [Logical operators in JavaScript — how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535647/logical-operators-in-javascript-how-do-you-use-them)) which will be either the value of `name` (if `name` is falsey) **or** `prop`.

The closest you can come to returning multiple values is to put them in a data structure and return that data structure.

e.g. an array:

```
return [name, prop];
```

or an object:

```
return { name, prop };
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use "return {name:name,prop:prop};" instead of  "return name && prop"
>   Because one value should be return at the time of function call

```
var contacts =[
    {
        "firstname": "karthi",
        "lastname": "kosuri",
        "mobile": "9999666888889",
        "likes":["pizza","icecream","curdrice"]
    },
    {
        "firstname": "sathvik",
        "lastname": "kosuri",
        "mobile": "9849488486",
        "likes":["biryani","vada","idly"] 
    },
    {
        "firstname": "neelu",
        "lastname": "kosuri",
        "mobile": "892736636",
        "likes":["annam","pappu","charu"]
    },
    {
    "firstname": "kesav",
    "lastname": "kosuri",
    "mobile": "748484848484",
    "likes":["kudithi","sambar","bokka"]
    }
];
// newcontact = JSON.stringify(contacts);
// console.log(newcontact)
function contactlookup(name, prop){
    for( var i=0; i< contacts.length;i++){
if(contacts[i].firstname=== name && contacts[i].lastname=== prop){
    **return {name:name,prop:prop}**
}

    }
return "no such name";

}
var data = contactlookup("karthi", "kosuri");
console.log(data);
```